# Calling template snippets stored in a DB

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play and its templating engine to generate web pages. The content of each page is (partially) stored in an SQL database, either as markup text or as plain HTML. Is it possible to include template snippets (without arguments) within this content?

Here is a small example. Let's say that I have some template `@printText()` and that this template has been imported at the top of the current view. The following content is stored in the database:

```
<div>
  @printText()
</div>
```

Is it possible to pass this String to the view and render it properly (including the call to `@printText()`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create for an example static method which will fetch snippet from the database by some key and use it in the view like:

```
<div id="footer_snippet">
    @Html(fetchSnippet("footer"))
</div>
```

It just should find your snippet in the DB and return the markup HTML as a `String`

Comment: This is not what I mean. It is not the snippet that is stored in the database, but the reference to that snippet.